# How to initial a jquery mobile flipswitch in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

**requirement:**
when i click a button ,send a ajax request ,get the result and create a list,in this list ,i wan't to use flip-switch widget
i know ,the flip-switch widget  won't initialed in the callback automatically,*but how could i initial it by myself?*
**what i tried?**
tried the fresh method,but get the error :"fresh can't be used before initial"
tried to trigger the  create event ,but it doesn't work.
appreciate your help!

```html
template:<li class="clearfix">
                    <span class="keyword-name">{{name}}</span>
                    <div class="keyword-monitor">
                        <select data-role="slider" data-mini="true" class="monitor" data-ruleid="{{rule_id}}" data-isoff="{{is_off}}" data-type="{{type}}">
                            <option value="0" >取消</option>     
                            <option value="1" >监测</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
    </li>
```

```js
  function initDefaultTab(index){
$.ajax({
  url:"/usercenter/defaultwords/"+index,
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json"      
}).done(function(data){
  var html="";
  var source = $("#default-keyword-template").text();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var $temp=$(template({
      name: data[i].name,
      rule_id: data[i].rule_id,
      is_off:data[i].is_off,
      type:data[i].type
    }));
    if(data[i].is_off===1){
      $temp.find("option").eq(0).attr("selected",true)
    }else{
      $temp.find("option").eq(1).attr("selected",true)
    }        
    html+="<li class='clearfix'>"+$temp.html()+"</li>";
  }
  var $html = $(html);     
  $("#defaultword-"+index).find("ul").append($html);
  $("#defaultword-"+index).find(".monitor").flipswitch({enhanced:true});
});}
```

Comment: What does your template source look like?

Comment: @ezanker i used select   ,i have already solved this problem ,because the flipswitch is  a type of slider ,so use $(".monitor").slider() will made the it like a flipswitch